# Server broadcasting to multiple websockets. Some are faster?

Tags: websocket

When a server broadcast the same info to multiple clients via websocket connection my idea is that some clients will receive the information faster (supposing the transmit time is the same for all clients) because after all the data going out the server is "serial".

Or is there something I'm missing? Can it be dependent on the implementation of the ws broadcast?

How can for example FOREX server be sure that all the clients receive the information about exchanges done at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There's never a guaranteed way that all the clients will receive the data at the same time.

Even if the data was sent at the same time (for example, using UDP broadcasting rather than a WebSocket connection), clients suffer from different network latency and routing, the data will still arrive at different times.

For WebSockets, the server itself will always send the data to some clients before it's sent to other clients...

...but this doesn't mean the data will arrive in the same order. Network latency, connectivity issues, intermediary performance and other uncontrollable concerns might make it so the data that was sent first arrives last. It's impossible to control.

Comment: Ok, so supposing I (as client) open multiple WS to the server for the same data, since the connectivity is (more or less) the same I should get some data faster in some connections. I'll try ;).

Comment: @MicheleTuloskiFurci, Good Luck :-) ... please note that, depending on your client, all the messages might be forced into a linear queue. For example, on a JavaScript client, all messages are queued as separate events and all events will fire sequentially... even messages that arrive at the same time will appear to have arrived one after the other. Also, unless the server is extremely busy (or slow), the time difference might be very small.